# using pyodbc in azure databrick for connecting with SQL server

Tags: pyodbc, databricks, azure-databricks

```
import pyodbc    

pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL SERVER};'
                  'Server=server name;'
                  'Database = database name;'
                  'UID='my uid;'
                  'PWD= 'my password;'
                  'Authentication = ActiveDirectoryPassword')
```

running above code in databrick notebook i am getting following error

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL SERVER' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Azure Databricks does not have ODBC Driver installed.

**For SQL Server:** You can resolve the issue by using the following script

```
sudo apt-get -q -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get -q -y install python3-dev
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pyodbc
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql
```

**For Azure SQL Database:** Run the following commands in a single cell to install MY SQL ODBC Driver on Azure Databricks cluster.

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting to Azure SQL DB? Could you please share the error message which you are experiencing?

Comment: https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark , i followed this link and changed Driver={SQL Driver} to Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}

Comment: now  i am getting this error 
OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Problem seems to be network related issue. I would request you to check the connect string passed and rerun.

Comment: code was correct, functional account  need to created for connecting with SQL server.. everything worked fine..

Comment: The SQL SERVER one throws a lot of error, and says it's missing dependencies that can't be installed. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What you posted looks like straight Python code.  In the Databricks environment, things are a little different than they are on your local machine.

Try it like this.

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```